# How-to activate the ZipArchive class in PHP 5.3 on CentOS

Tags: php, centos, installation, php-ziparchive

I read on the [documentation](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) I should only compile PHP 5.3.3 with "--enable-zip" parameter, but this doesn't work. I did this but `class_exists('ZipArchive')` always return `false`. What should I do next?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried installing ZipArchive using pecl?

```
$ pecl install zip
```

then add extension=zip.so to your php.ini

Comment: pecl is for most people probably in php-pear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Zip class is being loaded by your server by,

1. Write a quick phpinfo(); script and check if Zip is enabled; and
2. If it isn't, you can check the /etc/php.d/zip.ini file to make sure that the zip.so file is being loaded when PHP kicks off.
3. As you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) make sure you are using the class_exists function correctly for your version of PHP.

[ >= PHP 5.3]

If you are checking if a class exists that is in a specific namespace then you have to pass in the full path to the class:

echo (class_exists("com::richardsumilang::common::MyClass")) ? "Yes" : "No";

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it. Zip extension is active and ZipArchive class is native so there is no wrong way to check it.

Answer (score 0):

pecl install zip:
compilation terminated.
make: *** [php_zip.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed